# Undefined index: DATA in icici_standard.php

Tags: php, e-commerce

Undefined index: DATA in icici_standard.php

```
$data = html_entity_decode($this->request->post['DATA']);
$old_digest = strtolower($this->request->post['EncryptedData']);
```

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0):

try below code:

```
if(isset($this->request->post['DATA'])) {
    $data = html_entity_decode($this->request->post['DATA']);
} else {
    $data = '';
}

if(isset($this->request->post['EncryptedData'])) {
    $old_digest = strtolower($this->request->post['EncryptedData']);
} else {
    $old_digest = '';
}
```